# matchin URL with url patterns set contains regular expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, url

I have URL which should be matched with one of the URL pattern from  multiple URL patterns array

```
var URLPatternsArr = ['https://m.abc.com/collections/([^/]+)','https://m.abc.com/store/([^/]+)/','https://m.abc.com/collections/([^/]+)/item/([^/]+)']

url = 'https://m.abc.com/collections/tagline-silk-mill/item/green-embroidered-faux-georgette-salwar-anarkali-salwar-kameez--42cba667-256a-4f95-8912-62f3d03a128f'
```

the URLPatternsArr will contain n numbers of different URLs with regex. i will iterate this array & check exact match.
if I use javascript match function

```
 Object.keys(URLPatternsArr).forEach(function(el) {
     console.log("-------");
     console.log("matching with "+URLPatternsArr[el]);
        if(url.match(URLPatternsArr[el])  != null)
        {
          console.log("matched with "+URLPatternsArr[el]);
        }
      });
```

the url is matched with both `'https://m.abc.com/collections/([^/]+)'` and `'https://m.abc.com/collections/([^/]+)/item/([^/]+)'` ,

i want to match this URL with `'https://m.abc.com/collections/([^/]+)/item/([^/]+)'` as this patterns contians /item/ between two regular expression and URL contains same.
what will good method to find this type match in javascript or Node.js?

Comment: Wrap all your regular expressions with  `^` and `$` anchors. E.g. `^PATTERN$`

Answer (score 1):

Just change your patterns to match completly:

```
var URLPatternsArr = ['^https://m.abc.com/collections/([^/]+)$','^https://m.abc.com/store/([^/]+)/$','^https://m.abc.com/collections/([^/]+)/item/([^/]+)$']
```